# Как работает "Vertex Array Object" в openGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

Я так понимаю, VAO - это просто обертка над *конкретным* VBO? Т.е. через функцию `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...)` мы перекидываем данные с ОЗУ на GPU, а потом создаем отдельный объект-менеджер, который взаимодействует с шейдерами и который мы используем при отрисовке?
Еще хотелось бы иметь бинарное представление о VAO.

Comment: "бинарное представление"? Уточните вопрос, что и зачем вам нужно. В общем случае, это все лишь публичный контракт и детали реализации конкретных драйверов.

Comment: Это схоже с вопросом "Как Delete[] знает, сколько надо удалять?". Т.е. общий случай реализации, если сказать по другому.

Comment: Вот тут есть кое-какая информация: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/99236/what-state-is-stored-in-an-opengl-vertex-array-object-vao-and-how-do-i-use-the/99238#99238